# Many to many relationship is empty on policy, but not empty on testing?

Tags: laravel

I created a test for `belongsToMany` relationship but found that the relationship is empty when I `dd` inside policy.

`FieldReportPolicy.php`

```php
/**
 * Determine whether the user can view the model.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
 * @param  \App\Models\FieldReport  $fieldReport
 * @return mixed
 */
public function view(User $user, FieldReport $fieldReport)
{
    dd($fieldReport->taggedUsers); // <-- Here..

    return $user->can('view fieldReport')
        && $fieldReport->taggedUsers->contains(['id' => $user->id])
        || $user->getRoleNames()->contains('customer');
}
```

`Result`

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3262
  #items: []
}
```

However, inside the test, it is not empty. But it gave me 403 because I can't get the tagged users like i mentioned above.

`Feature\FieldReportTest.php`

```php
public function testShowShouldBeAccessibleByEmployeeThatAreTagged()
{
    $company = Company::factory()->createOne([
        'user_id' => $this->user->id,
    ]);

    $branch = Branch::factory()->createOne([
        'user_id' => $company->user_id,
        'company_id' => $company->id
    ]);

    $someone = User::factory()->createOne([
        'company_id' => $company->id,
        'branch_id' => $branch->id,
    ]);

    $report = FieldReport::factory()->createOne([
        'user_id' => $someone->id,
        'company_id' => $company->id,
        'branch_id' => $branch->id,
    ]);

    $report->taggedUsers()->attach($this->user);

    dd($report->taggedUsers); // <-- Here

    $this->actingAs($this->user->assignRole('employee'), 'api')
        ->getJson(route('fieldReports.show', $report))
        ->assertOk()
        ->assertJsonFragment($report->toArray());
}
```

`Result`

```php
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4915
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => App\Models\User {#5170
      #fillable: array:8 [
        ...
      ]
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

`Test Result (all dd commented out)`

```
   FAIL  Tests\Feature\FieldReportTest
  ✓ index should be accessible by customer
  ✓ index should be accessible by employee
  ✓ index should contains tagged reports when current logged in user is employee and has tagged by other employee
  ✓ index should be inaccessible by banned customer
  ✓ index should be inaccessible by banned employee
  ✓ index should be inaccessible by internal
  ✓ index should be inaccessible by moderator
  ✓ index should be inaccessible by guest
  ✓ show should be accessible by customer
  ⨯ show should be accessible by employee that are tagged

  Response status code [403] does not match expected 200 status code.
  Failed asserting that false is true.

  at C:\Users\Fukka\Documents\Laravel\myapp\tests\Feature\FieldReportTest.php:281
    277▕         // dd($report->taggedUsers);
    278▕
    279▕         $this->actingAs($this->user->assignRole('employee'), 'api')        
    280▕             ->getJson(route('fieldReports.show', $report))
  ➜ 281▕             ->assertOk()
    282▕             ->assertJsonFragment($report->toArray());
    283▕     }
    284▕
    285▕     public function testShowShouldBeInaccessibleByEmployeeThatAreUntagged()

  1   C:\Users\Fukka\Documents\Laravel\myapp\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:61   
      PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()


  Tests:  1 failed, 9 passed, 24 pending
  Time:   44.26s
```

Also please have a look at my model. I'm pretty sure I have it properly defined.

`FieldReport.php`

```php
/**
 * Each field report are belongs to many taggedUsers.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\BelongsToMany
 */
public function taggedUsers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        User::class,
        'field_report_participant',
        'field_report_id',
        'participant_id',
    );
}
```

`User.php`

```php
/**
 * Each user are belongs to many tagged field reports.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\BelongsToMany
 */
public function taggedFieldReports()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        FieldReport::class,
        'field_report_participant',
        'participant_id'
    );
}
```

So, why is this happen?

**UPDATE**

I don't use `Gate`s for authorization stuffs. I use only middlewares and policies for the entire app. Also here, I attached my route and controller file, I hope it will provide useful information.. Please have a look.

`api.php`

```php
Route::middleware(['auth:api', 'forbid_banned_user'])->group(function () {
    ...
    // Customer-Employee related.
    Route::middleware(['role:customer|employee'])->group(function () {
        ...
        Route::apiResource('fieldReports', FieldReportController::class);
        ...
    });
    ...
});
```

`FieldReportController.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\FieldReportRequest;
use App\Models\FieldReport;

class FieldReportController extends Controller
{
    protected $model;

    /**
     * Create new instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->authorizeResource(FieldReport::class, 'fieldReport');
        $this->model = new FieldReport;
    }

    ...
    ...
    
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\FieldReport  $fieldReport
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(FieldReport $fieldReport)
    {
        return response()->json($fieldReport);
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Seems like it doesn't have anything to do with the relationship. If you are getting 403 the problem is with authorization and the request is not getting to the controller. It is most likely failing in a middleware.

Comment: yaa.. i know the 403 has nothing to do with the relationship but there on my policy, i need the relationship to be compared with the client's id wether it was tagged or not. it is empty when i `dd` on it, so that `$fieldReports->taggedUsers->contains(['id' => $user->id])` method are always `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my.. I found the problem as well as the answer for this question. It was my mistake `dd`-ing on the Policy class. The test was dumped early even before it touches my targetted test case, the rest of the test were blocked because the app got `die`-ed, the `attach` method on my test case are not even get called. This is why I got an empty array.

The reason why I got `403` was here:

```php
$fieldReport->taggedUsers->contains(['id' => $user->id]);
```

I was awfully trying to check the existence of both key and value when the `taggedUsers` are already an array containing that key. The `contains` method are meant to be used to check an existence of value given in an array, not the entire key value pair.

I simply changed to this and it passes:

```php
$fieldReport->taggedUsers->contains($user->id)
```

Everything works as expected now. All tests passes.